# CORS error after every update. (Reinstall extenshion fix it)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors

I have chrome extension based on vue and native fetch.
Manifest version: 3
Host permissions looks like: ["https://*.site.com/", ...]
Fetch query did in background worker:

```js
 fetch(`https://sub.site.com/`, {credentials: 'include'});
```

It works when i install extension , but after updates from chrome store (creating new version) i receive cors error. When i delete extension and install it again magic happens and queries works.

Answer (score -1):

CORS error you need to solve in backend code.

In node.js you need add below code to resolve CORS error

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. 
1. Site is not mine, that why i can't. 
2. After reinstallation all work fine. 
3. Chrome allow to do queries even without this headers if extension have permissions for the site.